# send email to different recipient based upon drop-down selection

Tags: email, module

I have a select drop-down with different values in it on my contact form, and I want to direct the e-mail to a different person based upon the value selected in the drop down.  How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solspace's [Freeform](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/freeform/) has a [dynamic recipients functionality](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#recipients) that just might serve your needs.

I quote:

> `recipients="yes"`
>
> This parameter allows you to let your users select recipient email addresses dynamically within the form itself. So for example, you can have a dropdown select menu that allows your users to select the destination for their email (Sales, Support, Service, etc). You can have corresponding email addresses to those options and the result is that the user can direct which email the notification should go to.

Comment: so there's no way to do that without using freeform?

Comment: Sure there is, but you'd have to write that yourself with a little PHP on output.